# input argument in remix of a value sub 1

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

How to input/format a value such as 0.2 in the remix browser as percentage?

e.g. `function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value, uint256 percentage) public returns (bool);`

(don't mind the function it's for demonstrative purpose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uint256` is an integer type, so you can only pass integers. Solidity doesn't have any floating-point or fixed-point numbers.

A typical workaround is to use a rational number, i.e. a numerator and denominator, often with a fixed denominator. For example, when passing a percentage, instead of passing 0.2, pass 20 and divide by 100:

```
amount * percentage / 100
```

Comment: Pretty cool that they are experimenting with support for this in the future :) fixed-point numbers! also I tried with your suggestion of passing 20 and dividing by 100 however it get's rounded down to 0 so I guess it doesn't work for now :)

Comment: Yes, it does work. Make sure you multiply before dividing. 5 / 100 * 20 == 0, but 5 * 20 / 100 = 1. If that's not it, please share your code.

Comment: the thing is there is no 'amount' part of the calculation, I just want a percentage to show which is e.g. 0.2. so if argument for _percentage parameter = 20 and I want 0.2 to be shown as percentage I try _percentage.div(100); which gives 0. I tried with uint256(10).mul(_percentage).div(100); and set _percentage to 2 this time and it still gives 0.

Comment: What do you mean by "show?" Showing something would happen on the client side, where typically decimals are supported. For calculation within the smart contract, you need to keep it as 20 until it's time to do a calculation with it.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

import "./SafeMath.sol";

contract Percentage{

    uint public testvalue;

    ///apply a percentage as modifying factor to the token amount to transfer
    constructor(uint256 _value, uint256 percentage) public {

        // reduce the amount to transfer by 20 Percent
       uint transferAmount = (_value * SafeMath.sub(100, percentage)) / 100;

       //set testresult
       testvalue = transferAmount;
    }   
}
```

Comment: I'm not asking how to do percentage calculations in code, I'm asking how to format input for remix input field when inserting a sub 1 value as an argument for a function parameter. e.g. for the transfer function specified "0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c", 5 but for sub 1 values like 0.2 instead of 5

Comment: You need to put it in as a string and parse the amount of leading zeros and the last numnber(s).